# Voice to text - Alexa Voice Service

Tags: android, voice-recognition, alexa-skills-kit

I'm trying to make an android app which uses Alexa voice service to translate voice to text.A simple mic and text box app.

I'm new to android and need deep instructions to understand.

Comment: We're not a 'How To' service. We help with code related issues..

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get the voice to text conversion from Alexa ..However you can try the below library and understand the Alexa features.

https://github.com/willblaschko/AlexaAndroid

You can try the below sample for voice to text using android framework component and you dont need internet for it to work in the application its an offline recognition engine.

http://www.androidhive.info/2014/07/android-speech-to-text-tutorial/

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the links. 
The second link shows speech to text using google..but I want to use Alexa (or Lex) for speech conversion. Is there any method to achieve that?